# Enclose the year in parenthesis in a filename

Tags: bash, rename, awk

I have a group of files in a folder that I want to rename;  each file has a 4-digit year as part of the filename, I would like to enclose the years in parenthesis.

```
"Ghostbusters 3 2016.avi" to "Ghostbusters 3 (2016).avi"
"Caddyshack 1980.mp4" to "Caddyshack (1980).mp4"
etc...
```

I've tried to use rename with a regular expression but can't get it to work properly.

I appreciate the help!

Rada

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried and [with which `rename`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) Please respond by adding information to the question ([edit] the question).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out;

```
for file in * ; do echo "rename \"$file\" "$(echo \""$file" | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/(\1)/')\"; done | sed 's/$/ */'|bash
```

Thanks anyway!